# How to keep your current screen position while dynamically showing surrounding elements with jquery / css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a paragraph, for example, that I would like a user to focus on.
I would like to be able to load the surrounding text around the paragraph without moving the screen around and losing their place.  Is that possible?

```
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='hidden'>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    </div>

    <div>Text I want to keep anchored to</div>
    <br/><br/>
    <a href="javascript:$('.hidden').show()">show</a>

    <div class='hidden'>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't go this route originally because I thought there would be some "flashing" when scrolled.  I tried it, and am not seeing any.
This pretty much finds out where you are in relationship to your element, and when elements around it are displayed, it moves you back to where you were.
I noticed two problems with this solution:

1. It seems to be off by just a hair.  I am not sure why.  Barely noticeable.
2. With Chrome 38 on my Mac, there is apparently a redraw issue.  If you run this code, refresh, and run it again, it will scroll to the top of your page.  If you make a slight movement on the window it will refresh back to where it needs to be.  Apparently there are some repaint WebKit issues at play.

Hope that helps someone.  If there are better solutions, I'd like to see it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showFullContent()
    {
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var elementTop = $('.target').offset().top;

        var delta = windowTop - elementTop;

        $('.hidden').show();

        var newElementTop = $('.target').offset().top;

        $(window).scrollTop(newElementTop + delta);
    }

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.hidden').hide();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a fixed height for each container and toggle their visibility.

```
max-height: 100px;
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yh6k2xd3/)

Comment: I do not want the extra whitespace around the paragraph.  I thought I could do what you recommend, and hide the scroll bar.  When I click show, I make the text visible and display the scroll bar.  The problem is, what if my scroll bar is hidden and I need it in order to scroll my paragraph.  Make that div, itself, scrollable?  Hmm... I think I am answering my own question.  Is there a cleaner way?